# mesos agent keeps relaunching failed task infinitely

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Scheduler launches a task, Mesos Master (apache mesos 1.0.0) accepts and gives this task to a mesos agent. After that mesos agent keeps on running that task infinitely on failure. Is there a parameter to control retry for failed task.

Answer (score 0):

Which scheduler are you using (Restarting tasks is a schedulers responsibility)? 
Could it be you are using marathon? Marathon is designed for long-running tasks, i.e., it will restart (failed) tasks.

Comment: We are using cassandra framework by Mesosphere. So mesos agent runs a task once, and reports back to scheduler via mesos master, and then scheduler holds the responsibility of restarting failed tasks?

Comment: Yes it is the responsibility of the scheduler.